# Combine values of first and last row for rows where certain condition is met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this. It shows the raw data from a sensor on a machine.
Simple time spans for when the sensor is or is not triggered.

I want to combine certain rows and hide others. Let me explain.

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| Seq  |          Start          |           End           | trigger |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1286 | 2020-07-22 09:24:25.477 | 2020-07-22 09:24:25.770 |       0 |
| 1287 | 2020-07-22 09:24:25.773 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.627 |       1 |
| 1288 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.630 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.313 |       0 |
| 1289 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.317 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.720 |       1 |
| 1290 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.727 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.990 |       0 |
| 1291 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.993 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.180 |       1 |
| 1292 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.183 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.627 |       0 |
| 1293 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.630 | 2020-07-22 09:29:46.703 |       1 |
| 1294 | 2020-07-22 09:29:46.707 | 2020-07-22 09:29:47.037 |       0 |
| 1295 | 2020-07-22 09:29:47.040 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.083 |       1 |
| 1296 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.087 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.447 |       0 |
| 1297 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.450 | 2020-07-22 09:30:09.610 |       1 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

I filter out all the rows where `trigger` is 0 and `Start` to `End` is greater than one minute.

I try to do it like this:

```
SELECT [Seq], [Start], [End], [trigger]
FROM MyTableName
WHERE (trigger = 0 AND End-Start > '1900-01-01 00:01:00.000') 
   OR trigger=1
```

This query returns:

```
 
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| Seq  |          Start          |           End           | trigger |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1285 | 2020-07-22 09:24:24.347 | 2020-07-22 09:24:25.470 |       1 |
| 1287 | 2020-07-22 09:24:25.773 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.627 |       1 |
| 1288 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.630 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.313 |       0 |
| 1289 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.317 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.720 |       1 |
| 1290 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.727 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.990 |       0 |
| 1291 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.993 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.180 |       1 |
| 1293 | 2020-07-22 09:29:35.630 | 2020-07-22 09:29:46.703 |       1 |
| 1295 | 2020-07-22 09:29:47.040 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.083 |       1 |
| 1297 | 2020-07-22 09:29:58.450 | 2020-07-22 09:30:09.610 |       1 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

Now I want to join all rows between the zeroes to one row each, combining the `Start` of the first row, the `End` of the last row and the `SUM` of the rows that were combined into one, using either `trigger` or `Seq`.

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| Seq  |          Start          |           End           | trigger |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1285 | 2020-07-22 09:24:24.347 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.627 |       2 |
| 1288 | 2020-07-22 09:24:34.630 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.313 |       0 |
| 1289 | 2020-07-22 09:26:02.317 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.720 |       1 |
| 1290 | 2020-07-22 09:26:21.727 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.990 |       0 |
| 1291 | 2020-07-22 09:29:23.993 | 2020-07-22 09:30:09.610 |       4 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

If any of you guys could help me out or give me some hints on how to accomplish this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can explain what you want better if you explain the results, not how you want to get them.  What is in the result set?  I'm also a bit baffled by how the final column is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the feeling that you want to count periods where a period is defined as:

- A "0" row with more than 1 minute
- All such rows go in their own group

If so, you can use:

```
select min(seq), min(start), max(end), sum(trigger)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when trigger = 0 and end > dateadd(minute, 1, start) then 1 else 0 end) over (order by start) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp, (case when trigger = 0 and end > dateadd(minute, 1, start) then 1 else 0 end);
```

The second key on the `group by` puts the `0` row into its own group.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=734a6175739cf543ea5c62d072defe05) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Despite my poor exlaination, you managed to solve my problem. Thank you very much!